# Properly installing SQLite for Node.js

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, sqlite, npm

I follow the instructions on installing [SQLite](https://npmjs.org/package/sqlite3) for Node.js:

```
apt-get install sqlite3
apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
npm install sqlite3
```

Still, the code

```
var db = new require('sqlite3').verbose().Database('database.db');
```

results in the error message:

```
./node: symbol lookup error: /root/together2/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3_bindings.node: undefined symbol: _ZN2v814ObjectTemplate11SetAccessorENS_6HandleINS_6StringEEEPFNS1_INS_5ValueEEENS_5LocalIS2_EERKNS_12AccessorInfoEEPFvS7_NS6_IS4_EESA_ES5_NS_13AccessControlENS_17PropertyAttributeE
```

The system is:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS"
```

Can anyone explain what am I missing here?

Comment: That error appears to me that you are attempting to use the sqlite3 package with a different build of node.js than it was built for, hence  the missing symbol. You should rebuild the package against the version of node.js that you are requiring it from.

Comment: I reinstalled node and sqlite3 and now it works. I’m not sure but it may have been that npm was installed from the package manager while node from source. Thank you, I would accept your comment if it would be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error appears to me that you are attempting to use the sqlite3 package with a different build of node.js than it was built for, hence the missing symbol. You should rebuild the package against the version of node.js that you are requiring it from.